# MySQL stuck on "using filesort" when doing an "order by"

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, filesort

I can't seem to get my query to stop using filesort.

This is my query:

```
SELECT s.`pilot`, p.`name`, s.`sector`, s.`hull` 
FROM `pilots` p 
 LEFT JOIN `ships` s ON ( (s.`game` = p.`game`) 
  AND (s.`pilot` = p.`id`) ) 
WHERE p.`game` = 1 
 AND p.`id` <> 2 
 AND s.`sector` = 43 
 AND s.`hull` > 0 
ORDER BY p.`last_move` DESC
```

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pilots` (
  `id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_move` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `last_move` (`last_move`),
  KEY `game_id_lastmove` (`game`,`id`,`last_move`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ships` (
  `id` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pilot` mediumint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sector` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `hull` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '50',
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `game` (`game`),
  KEY `pilot` (`pilot`),
  KEY `sector` (`sector`),
  KEY `hull` (`hull`),
  KEY `game_2` (`game`,`pilot`,`sector`,`hull`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

The explain:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE     p  ref  id,game_id_lastmove  game_id_lastmove  1  const  7  Using where; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE     s  ref  game,pilot,sector...  game_2  6  const,fightclub_alpha.p.id,const  1    Using where; Using index
```

edit: I cut some of the unnecessary pieces out of my queries/table structure.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best thing that you can do is to make indexes:

1. index that covers table `ships` with fields: `game + pilot + sector + hull` (**in this specific order**)
2. `pilots`: `game + id`

this particular query will always use filesort, because it has not range condition p.id <> 2

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Didn't know that the NOT would force it to use filesort!

Does it matter what order your fields are when you make an index?

Comment: I just tried removing the p.id<>2 and it still used filesort. :(

Comment: after removing that condition new index should come: pilots: `game + last_move`. ps: <> not forcing to use filesort - it just avoids of using rightmost part of index. pps: yep, the order of fields in index is important

Comment: That seems to have worked great! I'll just remove p.id = 2 from the result set manually. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use
>   indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find
>   the rows that match the WHERE  clause.
>   These cases include the following ... 
>   The key used to fetch the rows is not
>   the same as the one used in the ORDER
>   BY